# Finding empty paragraph with space and remove it

Tags: jquery

Good Day

I want to remove the empty paragraph below one of my elements with the following code, and I am using the following code(see JS and fiddle).

My code is working, but I know the code is not very well written, I would like to be using (this) and not reference  to the elemtn each time. How would I optimize this code?

```
<div class="wpcol-one-quarter">
   <p><ahref=""><img src="" width="180" height="120" /></a></p>
</div>
<p>&nbsp;</p> <!--I want to remove this-->
<div class="wpcol-one-quarter">
   <p><a href=""><img src="" width="180" height="120" /></a></p>
</div>
```

JS:

```
$("div.wpcol-one-quarter").next('p:empty').remove();


if($("div.wpcol-one-quarter").next('p').html()=="&nbsp;") {
  $("div.wpcol-one-quarter").next('p').remove();
}
```

**NOTE: I ONLY want to remove this one empty p tag, not any other p tags that may be present on the page**

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/7L4WZ/126/)

thank you

Comment: If the code already works, maybe it's better to post it on Code review

Comment: thank you will do that next time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

cache the variable:

```
var p = $("div.wpcol-one-quarter").next('p');
if(p.html()=="&nbsp;") {
  p.remove();
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/7L4WZ/134/

Comment: thanks Pete, but as i told the others and said in my question, I just want to remove that one unique empty <p>, not everything...that is why I am using the .next()...

Comment: yeah, I thought you were after making your code more efficient which is what I have done for you

Answer (score 4):

You could do this :

```
$('p').filter(function(){ return $.trim(this.innerHTML)==="&nbsp;" }).remove();
```

I suggest to trim as a best practice because it's very easy to have spaces or line breaks inserted when you build some HTML.

[Demonstration](http://jsbin.com/etukax/1/edit)

Comment: would this not remove all empty p tags?

Comment: Thanks, but as I stated in my question, I only want to remove that one specific p tag...The one you see in the code below. Your code will remove all other empty <p> tags on the page which I do not want

Answer (score 0):

Try the below code:

```
$('p:empty').remove();
$('p').filter(function(){ return $.trim(this.innerHTML)==="&nbsp;" }).remove();
```

More help go to http://jsfiddle.net/7L4WZ/132/

Comment: Thanks, but as I stated in my question, I only want to remove that one specific p tag...The one you see in the code below. Your code will remove all other empty <p> tags on the page which I do not want